# INSERT INTO SELECT statement doesn't copy all selected records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two database, which are "OLD_DB" and "NEW_DB". I am trying to move data from OLD_DB to NEW_DB. I use script like below :

`INSERT INTO [NEW_DB].[dbo].[Table1](Field1,Field2,Field3) SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM [Linkserver].[OLD_DB].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Field4 = 1234`

*[Linkserver]: I use linked server because OLD_DB is in different server.*

I added script above in SQL SERVER Agent, so it will trigger itself on 5:00PM. At 5:00PM, my users were still working with OLD_DB. After they(users) left, I came to check my NEW_DB by using script like below :

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM [New_DB].[dbo].[Table1]
```

there are only 291 records. And I try to use SELECT statement in OLD DB

```
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3 FROM [Linkserver].[OLD_DB].[dbo].[Table1] WHERE Field4 = 1234
```

There are 431 records. then it turn into question, why does number of record in OLD_DB and NEW_DB are different ?

NOTE : I use SQL SERVER 2012 for both server.

Comment: why do you run it when they are still working as opposed to when they have left? surely that would be safer all around?

Comment: We'll need more info to troubleshoot this, I'm afraid. Is there a common pattern for the records that did make it into the new table? What about those "left behind"?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a unique index specified in the new table with the [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) option set to `ON`? That would have generated warnings but the `INSERT` would have succeeded.

Comment: Tanner : it is record synchronization, we plan to run it daily.
SchmitzIT : we code to update Field4 in OLD_DB, then we let SQL Server Agent move those info to NEW_DB.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever : I guess that would help if my scripts hit error, but in this case, It didn't show any error

Comment: trigger it whenever the cpu become ideal.

Comment: You could write something in an audit table, right after the synchronization is finished.

Comment: Can to try to move data between "OLD_DB" and "NEW_DB" using SSIS? This will help to decide if the issue is due to linked server or not.